# Regex not getting characters

Tags: regex

I have this regex

```
\.*?\{\{([\w\s]+)\|([\w\s]+)\}\}
```

and it captures the word like this correctly:

```
{{58afc8ed3688d3001cb8b043_1487915885599|data}}
```

But if I put a word like this

```
{{58afc8ed3688d3001cb8b043_1487915885599|data?}}
```

it fails capturing it.

How am I supposed to capture the later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following *regex* :

```
.*?\{\{([\w\s]+)\|(.*?)\}\}
```

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/r0pYve/2)

Comment: It's not working in my replace function in javascript

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between your two examples is that you have an extra '?' character in (or after) the second group.

[siam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42432945/413354)'s answer is correct, but will result in a very broad match which might not be what you want. After all, in the extreme case you could replace the whole regex with `\{\{(.*)\|(.*)\}\}` if you wanted.

Assuming it's only a question mark you're concerned with, you could:

- add that to your acceptable characters anywhere in your group by
  extending `([\w\s]+)` to `([\w\s?]+)`
- add it explicitly to the end of
  your group, replacing `([\w\s]+)` with `([\w\s]+\?*)` (which will
  allow zero or any number of trailing question marks)
- add it after the
  group if you don't care about capturing it with `([\w\s]+)\?*`

Of course, if you mean to accept special characters other than just the question mark you can simply keep adding them in the same way.

Comment: Thank you i now understand the concept behind this

Answer (score 0):

`\.*?\{\{([\w\s]+)\|([\w\s?]+)\}\}` should do the trick. `\w\s` won't catch a question mark.

Comment: Show what if i put other characters there

Comment: Do you know which characters in advance? If you do, also place those between the last square brackets. If you don't, you need '.*' to guarantee a match. If you want everything but whitespace, try `\S`.